# Extending Django with sites app to provide current working app as SAAS

Tags: python, django, django-contrib

I have a working deployed Django application in production, with some users and various objects stored in the database. The client told me if the website could be replicated changing some minor things, such as templates, logos, etc. but maintaining some of the users and objects.

I had heard of `django.contrib.sites` long ago, so after reading the description it seemed the perfect choice. I went straight hands on, adding `django.contrib.sites` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, putting the `SITE_ID` in my `settings.py`, and performing the migrations.

I chose to use a `ManyToManyField` for the sites, since the users might be able to login in one or more of the sites:

```
sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

Since I have modified managers for some models, like the `User`, I had to override my custom `get_queryset`, to only return the current site users, so I added the `filter(sites=settings.SITE_ID)` to the returned queryset, as I saw in the documentation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            is_active=True).filter(sites=settings.SITE_ID)
```

For other classes, since I didn't override the default manager, I just did override the `objects`:

```
objects = CurrentSiteManager()
```

Everything was working fine until I tried to test my current working app. Since the objects in the database do not have an associated site (the `User.sites` queryset is empty) I am not able to login with any user.

Thus, I have gone back, reverted the migrations (that take into account the modification of managers), and now I am in the initial state, before any site modification.

I have been trying to find documentation on how to approach this, but I have yet not found a tutorial or some good practices on how to perform this "initial" data migration for sites when there is data already in the DB.

My guess is that I have to perform the sites migrations, then assign the current (and only) working site to all the data (users, and related objects), then change the managers and run the managers migrations. Is that it? Or am I missing something?

Any help or insight would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, it sounds like the problem is that with your change, a user now MUST be tied to at least one site to be able to login. Since your current users are not associated with any sites, this creates the login issue.

If this is the case, I would suggest adding a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) after the schema migrations in your branch. This data migration would loop through all of the users and add `settings.SITE_ID` to `user.sites`. You will also want to create a function that does the opposite, removes the entry from `user.sites` in case you need to rollback, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runpython).

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. That was what I did, and it worked. Just a quick question: is it really mandatory to implement the rollback? My guess is that in case I need to go back, since the model migration would delete the Site models, the reference would disappear and thus, the objects deleted, am I right?

Comment: Well, I'm not positive but it might actually create a foreign key error when you try to delete, because you are trying to remove a model that is being referenced by objects in your database. More importantly, IMHO it is just good practice to create rollback for all of your data migrations.

Comment: I definitely agree to that good practice, anyway. Thanks for the tip!